# How can I remove Materialize's select dropdown when using select2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select, materialize

I use both MaterializeCSS and Select2, and have a normal :

```
<label>Seleção de PFJ</label>
<select id="manual-download-pfj-select" name="pfj-select" multiple></select>
```

And then:

```
$("#manual-download-pfj-select").select2({width: "100%"});
```

All ok except for one problem:

[image]

I get this annoying dropdown repetition (Which is the default one from MaterializeCSS, but it has no search function, so I want to just remove it). [I've seen libraries](https://github.com/nikitasnv/materialize-select2) to combine MaterializeCSS and Select2, but they're useless since they only change the colours / theme, keeping the useless repetition. Either one, or the other, *with* the search function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the `browser-default` class, which tell the framework to skip the element:

```
<div class="row">
  <label class="">Seleção de PFJ</label>
    <select class="browser-default" multiple>
      <option value="1">example 1</option>
      <option value="2">example 2</option>
      <option value="3">example 3</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

This will keep the search functionality of `Select2`:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to do it by removing the visilibity of the select-wrapper directly:

```
.select-wrapper {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Which is far from ideal, but it seems to be the only way. *Now* I can use those .css adaptations to make Select2 look like MaterializeCSS.